# unique id throughout application lifetime

Tags: java

I am developing a jboss Java EE application where I need to send messages through a messaging system (JMS or AMQP optional). Approx. there will be around 10k to 15k messages per second. The requirement is to generate a unique id for each outgoing message that is not used any time in the past, even after application restart i.e. the id should not repeat again through the application lifetime (from day 1 of application use until decommissioned)

I will prefer solutions based on

1. Numeric value only (what data type?)
2. String

The auto-generation of the id should be atomic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java provides a method for generating [Universally Unique Identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) in the [UUID class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

Wikipedia has an explanation why the probability that these generate a message with the same ID is negligible.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to like UUIDs, especially since you can easily create them from disparate sources.  But you could also just use a long (64 bit) integer.  At 15k messages per second, you would get approximately 39 million years worth of unique numbers (half that if you want them to be greater than zero).

Comment: Plain `long`s would have to be a sequence, which would require persisting to survive application restarts. So the problem shifts to safely writing out to some sort of storage 15k times per second, or otherwise optimising this somehow. I believe databases do it by allowing gaps in the sequence and consuming "blocks" of IDs. (As well as doing an `AtomicLong` increment that many times without parallelisation.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a fast and simple take look at: [UIDGenerator.java](https://code.google.com/p/spf4j/source/browse/trunk/spf4j-core/src/main/java/org/spf4j/concurrent/UIDGenerator.java)

You can customize it (unique to process only, or world), it is easy to use and fast:

```
    private static final UIDGenerator SCA_GEN = new UIDGenerator(new ScalableSequence(0, 100));
.......
    SCA_GEN.next();
```

see my benchmarking results at:

http://zoltran.com/roller/zoltran/entry/generating_a_unique_id

or run them yourself.